# applicationDidFinishLaunching not running

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

So I'm starting out with cocoa and ObjC. I'm trying to follow the example in the up and running objective C/cocoa book from oreilly. My applicationDidFinishLaunching doesn't seem to be getting called. I think it's a problem with the way I hooked everything up in the IB.

Header: http://pastebin.com/6AdQt1uN

Class: http://pastebin.com/VCQWJWkj

IB: http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/4616/screenshot20110216at111.png

Does anyone see anything obvious that my untrained eyes do not?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Does your `Application` object have it's delegate set to your `Application App Delegate` object? Right click on `Application` in your IB window and set the `delegate` outlet to be your `Application App Delegate` object.

Comment: That did it. Onward to more debugging :D Thank you (will accept answer in 2 minutes).

Comment: Just commented on the other one too - glad it worked! Enjoy learning Cocoa :)

Answer (score 2):

A guess: you didn't set the object where you defined applicationDidFinishLaunching as the delegate for your app.

Comment: Didn't I do that as shown by the picture in the referencing outlets section? I right clicked on Window, and dragged delegate outlet to my class file in the document view (in the IB).

Comment: That's for the *Window*, not the *Application*. They're two different objects. See my answer below - you need to set the delegate on the Application itself.

Answer (score 0):

for those who do not use IB, make sure you specify the app delegate in main.m in the following way:

```
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

instead of:

```
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```